# Not in compliance with the answer sheet - IELTS listening section

Tags: ielts

In Cambridge IELTS 2 Test 1, in the 10th question you hear the narrator expressing that "Louise's card will be ready **until next week.**"
The question asks you "when will Louise's card be ready?" I wrote down "until next week", but the book gives the followings as the correct answers:
next week/ in a week/ in one week/ the following week.
Would i get a mark for my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo in the sentence? I suggest it was actually

> Louise's card will ***not*** be ready until next week.
>   When will Louise's card be ready?
>
> next week / in a week / in one week / the following week

In that case your proposed answer

> until next week

is incorrect because that means the card is ready now. But it isn't ready, and the correct answer is

> next week

---

On the other hand if there is no typo the question is

> Louise's card will be ready until next week.
>   When will Louise's card be ready?
>
> next week / in a week / in one week / the following week

and the answer is "now" or "this week" – but those are not options.